# DOS FOR command option tokens=07 works but not tokens=08

Tags: cmd, dos

I'm using Windows 2008 R2 in US English locale.  My batch file stopped working after August 1st.  It was working fine from March until July.

The script converts a numerical month with leading zero to string.  Here is the script to reproduce.   The actual batch script extracts the numerical month from %date%.

```
set month=07

REM convert numerical month to string
for /f "tokens=%month%" %%A in (
    "jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec") do (
    set month_str=%%A
)
echo %month_str%
```

Above runs fine.  It shows "jul"

But if I change the month to 08 it failed with error message

```
8" was unexpected at this time
```

So I removed the leading zero.

```
set /A month=100%month% %% 100
```

Now it's working fine again, and here is my questions

1. Where is the official documentation of FOR command for Windows 2008 R2?

EDIT: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754900.aspx

1. It's probably my fault to pass zero padded number to the tokens option but why 07 was acceptable and not 08?
2. If 07 is valid parameter, is it same as 7 or interpreted as something else?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal

Comment: That was my first guess having Unix background. Hence the question (1).

Comment: Hmmm and bingo! set month=010 returned aug!  so FOR command understands octal.  It's a kind of surprise.

Comment: Windows is full of surprises.

Comment: numerical parsing is documented under the SET command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments to the question it appears you have realized that Windows is attempting to treat 08 as octal, which of course fails.

Whenever a CMD.EXE internal command needs to parse a number, it treats any numeric string prefixed with `0` as octal and any numeric string prefixed with `0x` as hexadecimal. The numbers can optionally be prefixed with a sign as well. The numbers are limited to the values that can be expressed as an signed 4 byte integer: -2147483648 through 2147483647.

The only place I'm aware that Microsoft documentation talks about hexadecimal and octal numeric support is with the /A option of the SET command. But it appears that all strings that are treated as a number are treated the same way.

This inclues:

**1) SET /A**

```
set /a 010+0xA
18
```

**2) FOR /F TOKENS and SKIP options**

```
for /f "tokens=010" %A in ("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10") do @echo %A
8
```

**3) FOR /L**

```
for /l %N in (010 1 0xA) do @echo %N
8
9
10
```

**3) IF numeric comparison**

```
if 012==0xA echo match
match
```

**4) Variable expansion using a substring operation** (an example with negative numbers)

```
set "test=0123456789ABCDEF"
echo %test:~-0xA,-010%
67
```

That's all I can think of at the moment, but there may be others.